# Рекурсивна ли функция?

Tags: рекурсия, javascript

Функция `Load()` загружает аджаксом некоторый контент. В контенте есть **кнопка**, при клике на которую  вызывается опять же функция `Load()`, которая опять-таки загружает этот же контент, но с другими параметрами.
Вопрос знатокам: если кликнуть на эту  **кнопку** over 9000 раз, произойдет ли `stack overflow`? Мое мнение таково, что функция `Load()` в данном случае не является рекурсивной и никаких `overflow` не случится. А ваше?

Comment: Если скрипт загружает аяксом страницу, которая загружает аяксом страницу и т.д. — это рекурсия. Тут же есть преграда в виде нажатия кнопки пользователем, следовательно, рекурсией это считать не стоит.

Comment: Неужели так сложно кликнуть 9000 раз и проверить?

Comment: @Crasher, спасибо за помощь. Слово рекурсия вызывает у меня панику еще с тех пор, когда я в детстве взял в руки калькулятор МК-61. ))

Comment: @Равнодушный, кликать не сложно, сложно увидеть, что происходит при этом с ОЗУ.

Comment: @Deus, кликать то можно, но есть ли смысл делать вручную то, что можно имитировать кодом?

Comment: А что значит "загружает аяксом"? Выдаёт запрос и выходит. Запрос сам по себе выполняется, по завершении вызывается callback, который делает что надо и возвращает управление. И где тут рекурсия?

Comment: @Crasher, аджакс загружает фотки.Снизу ссылки "назад" и "вперед", по этим кликам контент и перезагружается на основании выбора пользователя

Comment: @Deus, от этого факт того, что нужно нажать, чтобы продолжились действия, не изменяется.
@alexlz, кстати, да, нужно взять во внимание асинхронность подачи\возвращения запроса

Comment: @Crasher, про ссылки "вперед" и "назад" - это был ответ на ваш комментарий :  <i>но есть ли смысл делать вручную то, что можно имитировать кодом</i>?

Comment: @Deus, я имел ввиду, что в процессе тестирования, чтобы смотреть на то, что происходит с ОЗУ и другое, вместо кликания вручную, можно просто имитировать нажатия кодом.

Comment: @Deus, очевидно, что никакой рекурсии здесь нет. Один и тот же контекст меняется при перезагрузке (нажатии на кнопку).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Что касается вызова вашей функции `Load`: каждый раз функция отрабатывает, выводит на экран контент и **заканчивает работу**. Следующий вызов инициирует пользователь нажатием кнопки (конечно, если я правильно понял), так что можно считать - `Load` работает в цикле, ни о каком рекурсивном вызове речи быть не может. Но вопрос об утечке памяти остается открытым. Полагаю речь идет о `jQuery.ajax()`. Так вот (читать до конца):

[xmlhttprequest.ru](http://xmlhttprequest.ru):

> В Internet Explorer объект XmlHttpRequest принадлежит миру DOM/COM, а Javascript-функция - миру Javascript. Присваивание xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { ... } задает неявную круговую связь: xmlhttp ссылается на функцию через onreadystatechange, а функция, через свою область видимости - видит (ссылается на) xmlhttp.
>
> Невозможность обнаружить и оборвать такую связь во многих (до IE 6,7 редакции июня 2007?) версиях Internet Explorer приводит к тому, что XmlHttpRequest вместе с ответом сервера, функция-обработчик и всё замыкание прочно оседают в памяти до перезагрузки браузера.
>
> Чтобы этого избежать, ряд фреймворков (YUI, dojo...) вообще не ставят onreadystatechange, а вместо этого через setTimeout проверяют его readyState каждые 10 миллисекунд. Это разрывает круговую связку xmlhttp <-> onreadystatechange, и утечка памяти не грозит даже в самых глючных браузерах.

[jQuery.ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> No `onreadystatechange` mechanism is provided, however, since done, fail, always, and statusCode cover all conceivable requirements.

Это в общем означает, что вышеупомянутое узкое место не используется в `jQuery.ajax`.

Comment: @KaZaца, "Это в общем означает, что вышеупомянутое узкое место не используется в jQuery.ajax." - это что означает? В $.ajax многократное использование Load() все-таки приведет к утечке памяти в ИЕ?

Comment: нет, они так-же не вешают обработчик на onreadystatechange

Comment: @Deus, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).